# Get a txt box id, from a text box

Tags: jquery, ajax

Afternoon,

I am setting the ID's for a multiple text boxes in my code for items returned from the database.
For example...

```
<input type="text" id="abcd1234" value="0.00">
```

basically the id is set when the items are returned, i need to get the id using jQuery so i can then update the value within the textbox with a new price.

I need to return 1) the id, and 2) the value so i can then process it. Could any one suggest how i could do this please?

UPDATE: This is the update function i am looking to use... please ignore the data being passed over cause i will update this once i am able to get the price from the textbox mentioned above. - removed the data. :)

```
$('.update').live('click', function () {
    $('#saving').show();


    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "../Web.asmx/UpdateData",
        data: **JSON will go here**,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#saving').hide();
            $('#infoMsg').show();
            $('#infoMsg').addClass('er-green');
            $('#infoMsg').html("Product was updated successfully.");
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            $('#saving').hide();
            $('#infoMsg').show();
            $('#infoMsg').addClass('er-yellow');
            $('#infoMsg').html("We are unable to update the product at this time.");
        }
    });
});
```

Many thanks...

Alan

Comment: get the id on what event ? click ?

Comment: Are you using an AJAX call to update the value of the `input`? Please elaborate a bit more on your question

Comment: sorry, yeah i will update the code now...

Comment: @thatuxguy - Are you aware that [`live` is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com)? Unless you're using an ancient version of jQuery you should be using `on` (1.7+) or `delegate`.

Comment: @JamesAllardice no i was not aware of that... do you have an example i can see so i can update my code?

Comment: @thatuxguy - See [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You need to bind the event handler to an ancestor element and pass `.update` as the 2nd argument.

Comment: @thatuxguy just literally replace the word live with on lol

Comment: lol so i see now :D @PhillipSchmidt

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - Not quite. That will only work if the elements exist in the DOM at the time the code runs. If not, you need to pass a selector to `on` and attach the event to an ancestor element.

Comment: @JamesAllardice good point. I don't do a lot of front-end work and I wasn't thinking about dynamically generated DOM elements

Comment: i suppose i could set the id of the table row, and use that to get the textbox value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which event you want the ID of the input element. The below script will give you the ID of all Input element of type text once the DOM is loaded

```
$(function(){

  var items=$("input[type='text']");
  $.each(items,function(){
    var item=$(this);

    var itemId=item.attr("id");  // get the ID of element
    alert(itemId);

    item.val("New value");  // set new value
  });

});
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/p5zbT/4/

**EDIT  : as per the comment**

To get he textboes belongs to one table, change your selector  like this

```
 var items=$("#dataTable input[type='text']");
```

This will select the `input` elements of type `text` inside a table(or any HTML element) with `ID` value as `dataTable`.

Working Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/p5zbT/9/

Comment: looks good, but i have some other txt boxes on the page, is there a way to look at the ones within my table? #dataTable

Comment: @thatuxguy: Change your jQuery selector. See my updated answer.

Comment: nice, looks like it could be what i am after, next up will be split them up and make some nice JSON to pass over :) I will have a play.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a clean way to do this -- and generally, it shouldn't really be done. The point of using IDs is really the opposite of this -- to find controls using the id, not to find ID's using other attributes. (Hint: if you really want to do it, look into other attributes that you can put on the control, and search for it using that.)

and edit: Just thought of a better way. Wrap that input in a div, find that div by id, and then parse it for child elements

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('input[type=text]'), function(i,obj){
  console.log('ID : '+$(this).attr('id')+', Value : '+$(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you're asking, but if you need to go over all the input elements and do something to them, you can use the following jQuery code

```
$("input[type='text']").each(function() {
    // do work here
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what i did was set the ID of the table row, which was the easiest option!

Once i had this i was able to get the sku/id, and the textbox value and update the DB like that.

Many thanks to everyone for you help and solutions :)